# Typescript Dictionary with promises as values

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

There is array of objects of type `User`. They have an asynchronous function that we need to value of. How can we assign the value of a dictionary to a promise and then resolve them all at once?

```
const userToFooPromises: { [userId: number]: Promise<Foo[]> } = { }
```

Is there an equivalent to `Promise.all(...)` for dictionary? We want to have the return type of `{ [userId: number]: Foo[] }`

Comment: Promise libraries like bluebird have [helper methods](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.props.html) that would work here, but otherwise, you'll need to map your dictionary to an array.

Answer (score 2):

You could separate the object into entries, run `Promise.all` on the mapped values, reassign the values with the resolved ones, and then reconstruct the object.

```js
const entries = Object.entries(userToFooPromises);
const resolved = await Promise.all(entries.map(o => o[1]));

entries.forEach(o => o[1] = resolved[1]);

Object.fromEntries(entries);
```